# On Page load drop down value not set using angular2-multiselect

Tags: angular

On refreshing the page, angular2-multiselect drop down does not display the default value. If i click anywhere on the screen then it is displayed. 
How to set the default value on refresh?
Code:

```
<angular2-multiselect
    [data]='statusList'
    [(ngModel)]='selectedStatus'
    [settings]='statusSettings'
    (onSelect)='onStatusSelect($event)'
    (onDeSelect)='onStatusDeSelect($event)'
    (onSelectAll)='onStatusSelectAll($event)'
    (onDeSelectAll)='onStatusDeSelectAll($event)'>
</angular2-multiselect>
```

Comment: how are you populating this onngInit can you show that component too

Comment: Check weather  your "statusList" is an object or Array

Comment: this.statusList = [
                        {'id': 1, 'itemName': this.translate.instant('timecard-status.approved')},
                        {'id': 2, 'itemName': this.translate.instant('timecard-status.open')},
                        {'id': 3, 'itemName': this.translate.instant('timecard-status.rejected')},
                        {'id': 4, 'itemName': this.translate.instant('timecard-status.submitted')}
                      ];

Comment: I have one component which is calling other component where i have used 'angular2-multiselect'